# Python unable to install guesslang

Tags: python, pip, language-detection

I'm trying to install `guesslang` with pip but it seems that the last version (which was released on August 2021) depends on an obsolete version of Tensorflow (`2.5.0`). The problem is that I can't find this version anywhere.
So, how can I install it? Or is there any other python library that does language detection?

However here's the error I get when trying to install it, maybe I misunderstood...

```
> pip install guesslang
Collecting guesslang
  Using cached guesslang-2.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (2.5 MB)
  Using cached guesslang-2.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (2.5 MB)
  Using cached guesslang-2.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
  Using cached guesslang-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
  Using cached guesslang-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (13.0 MB)
  Using cached guesslang-0.9.3-py3-none-any.whl (3.2 MB)
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.24.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (14.8 MB)
Collecting guesslang
  Using cached guesslang-0.9.1-py3-none-any.whl (3.2 MB)
ERROR: Cannot install guesslang==0.9.1, guesslang==0.9.3, guesslang==2.0.0, guesslang==2.0.1, guesslang==2.0.3, guesslang==2.2.0 and guesslang==2.2.1 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    guesslang 2.2.1 depends on tensorflow==2.5.0
    guesslang 2.2.0 depends on tensorflow==2.5.0
    guesslang 2.0.3 depends on tensorflow==2.5.0
    guesslang 2.0.1 depends on tensorflow==2.2.0
    guesslang 2.0.0 depends on tensorflow==2.2.0
    guesslang 0.9.3 depends on tensorflow==1.7.0rc1
    guesslang 0.9.1 depends on tensorflow==1.1.0

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tensorflow` 2.5.0 [released](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.5.0/#files) wheels for Python 3.6-3.9. Downgrade to Python 3.9 to install `guesslang` with `tensorflow` 2.5.0.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to fork the repository and remove the tensorflow version from the requirements.txt. As of May 13rd, Tensorflow 2.12 is the latest version for Python 3.10 and guesslang works without any issues. If you're lazy, you can use my fork (although there is no guarentees that I will keep this fork synced to the main guesslang repository):

https://github.com/kutlay/guesslang

Comment: Thank you so much random internet person.